# How to create an instance of model while it's data get from an external API in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a Product model have the following field

```
class Product(models.Model):
  
  id = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  thumbnail_url = models.URLField(max_length=255)
  short_description = models.TextField()
  price = models.FloatField()
  list_price = models.FloatField()
  price_usd = models.FloatField()
  discount = models.FloatField()
  discount_rate = models.FloatField()
  rating_average = models.FloatField()
  product_group_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  description = models.TextField()
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and serializer class for the Product model

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta: 
    model = Product
    fields = '__all__'
```

the view for API

```
class ProductList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
  queryset = Product.objects.all()
  serializer_class = ProductSerializer

  def perform_create(self, serializer):
    # calling external api in here
```

What I want to do here is that when I create a new Product. I'll only pass the id of the product, and then, calling an API to get the rest of the data for my model (by using the request library) and then attach those data in the body of the request so I can able to create a `Product` instance. So, how do I do that with DRF, I'd think of calling external API in `peforme_create()` method but I still have to pass all the field of the model in the body of the request

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Name of fields from external api are same as your model field names?

Comment: not really. The data from external API have much information and I only need a part of that. But I don't think the name of fields is a problem here?